# Clean the data in an efficient way in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

I have a data in the following format :

TOP  (S  (PP-LOC **(IN In)**  (NP  (NP **(DT an)** **(NNP Oct.)** **(CD 19)** **(NN review)** ) (PP **(IN of)**  (NP **()**  (NP-TTL **(DT The)** **(NN Misanthrope)** ) **('' '')**  (PP-LOC **(IN at)**  (NP  (NP **(NNP Chicago)** **(POS 's)** ) **(NNP Goodman)** **(NNP Theatre)** )))) (PRN  **(-LRB- -LRB-)** **()**  (S-HLN  (NP-SBJ **(VBN Revitalized)** **(NNS Classics)** ) (VP **(VBP Take)**  (NP **(DT the)** **(NN Stage)** ) (PP-LOC **(IN in)**  (NP **(NNP Windy)** **(NNP City)** )))) **(, ,)** **('' '')**  (NP-TMP **(NN Leisure)** **(CC &)** **(NNS Arts)** ) **(-RRB- -RRB-)** ))) **(, ,)**  (NP-SBJ-2  (NP  (NP **(DT the)** **(NN role)** ) (PP **(IN of)**  (NP **(NNP Celimene)** ))) **(, ,)**  (VP **(VBN played)**  (NP **(-NONE- *)** ) (PP **(IN by)**  (NP-LGS **(NNP Kim)** **(NNP Cattrall)** ))) **(, ,)** ) (VP **(VBD was)**  (VP  (ADVP-MNR **(RB mistakenly)** ) **(VBN attributed)**  (NP **(-NONE- *-2)** ) (PP-CLR **(TO to)**  (NP **(NNP Christina)** **(NNP Haag)** )))) **(. .)** ))

(TOP  (S  (NP-SBJ **(NNP Ms.)** **(NNP Haag)** ) (VP **(VBZ plays**)  (NP (**NNP Elianti)** )) **(. .)** ))

..... (There are 7000 more..)

This data was taken from a newspaper. A new line is a new sentence (begins with 'TOP')
From this data I need only the bold parts (without the parenthesis) for each sentence:

```
(IN In)(DT an) (NNP Oct.) (CD 19) (NN review) (IN of) (`` ``) (DT The) (NN Misanthrope)   ('' '')  (IN at)  (NNP Chicago) (POS 's) (NNP Goodman) (NNP Theatre)(-LRB- -LRB-) (`` ``)     (VBN Revitalized) (NNS Classics) (VBP Take) (DT the) (NN Stage)  (IN in)   (NNP Windy) (NNP    City) (, ,) ('' '') (NN Leisure) (CC &) (NNS Arts) (-RRB- -RRB-)(, ,) (DT the) (NN role)(IN of)  (NNP Celimene) (, ,) (VBN played) (-NONE- *)(IN by)(NNP Kim) (NNP Cattrall) (, ,) (VBD was)  (RB mistakenly)(VBN attributed) (-NONE- *-2) (TO to)(NNP Christina) (NNP Haag) (. .)

(NNP Ms.) (NNP Haag) (VBZ plays)(NNP Elianti)(. .)
```

I tried the following:

```
f = open('filename')
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

this part is to crate an array of tuples for each row (using regular expressions):

```
tag_word_train = numpy.empty((5000), dtype = 'object')
for i in range(0,5000) :
    tag_word_train[i] = re.findall(r'\(([\w.-]+)\s([\w.-]+)\)',data[i])
```

it takes a very long time so I couldn't tell if it is even correct

Do you have any idea how to do it in an efficient way?

Thanks,

Hadas

Comment: @Marcin Have you even read the question before editing? Your edit maee the bold parts the OP refer to invisible.

Comment: Sorry. Was too quick.

Comment: Where is the data from? `Stanford Parser` or `nltk` (something else?)?

Comment: Hi Reut, I don't know...

Comment: @Hadas Well, just so you know - this data should be modelled as a tree. Using a regex may work fora simple exercise, but if this is a project you're working on - see how common NLP libraries handle it.

Comment: Thanks! is there anything you can recommend of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nltk.tree` provides functions that both read in a parse and extract the pairs of words and part-of-speech tags that you want in your output:

```
>>> import nltk.tree
>>> t = nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring("(TOP (S (NP-SBJ (NNP Ms.) (NNP Haag) ) (VP (VBZ plays) (NP (NNP Elianti) )) (. .) ))")
>>> t.pos()
[('Ms.', 'NNP'), ('Haag', 'NNP'), ('plays', 'VBZ'), ('Elianti', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')]
```

Answer (score 2):

`nltk` has [a `Tree` class](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html) that probably suits your needs. In particular, you'll want to use the class method [`nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring):

```
>>> import nltk.tree
>>> nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring("(S (NP (DT The) (N cat)) (VP (V ran)))")
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['The']), Tree('N', ['cat'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('V', ['ran'])])])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

f = open('filename')
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
tag_word_train = numpy.empty((5000), dtype = 'object')
exp = re.compile("\([^()]*\)")

i = 0

for line in data:
    #out = re.findall(exp, data)
    #print(out)
    tag_word_train[i] = re.findall(exp, data)               
    i = i + 1
```

Breaking the regular expression down:

`\(` match a left parentheses

`[^()]*` match zero or more characters that are *not* the left or right parenthesis

`\)` match a right parenthesis

(I am assuming that what you want is terms which don't themselves include a parenthesised term.  If I am wrong in that assumption, the regex won't do what you want).

Comment: I get an error in 'out'. In addition I would like to have each row data separately (in a list or array or something similar) which I'm not sure this is the case in your answer. Thank you for your answer

Comment: When I use my answer on the input you provide above, I get the output you say you want.  I have edited my answer to show how to combine it with your existing code, in case that is the problem.  If you want the output stored, then instead of `out = re.findall(exp, data)` and `print(out)` you want `tag_word_train[i] = re.findall(exp, data)` (I don't know numpy but I'm assuming you do and have declared the right kind of list there).